# Efficiently remove a maximum amount of binary elements while keeping row and column sums above a certain level

Tags: python, optimization

I have the following problem and I'm having difficulty writing an optimized program for it.

I'm given a 2D binary numpy array (all elements are either 0 or 1, and its shape is (n, m)), and I need to remove the maximum number of elements from the array, while maintaining the property that the sum of each row is above `min_x` and the sum of each column is above `min_y`.

I've written the following non-optimized code which works well for small arrays:

```py
import numpy as np
from typing import Optional, Tuple
from itertools import product
from tqdm import tqdm

def min_dataset(data, min_x, min_y):
    '''Data is a row-major numpy array of shape (n, m), consisting of only 0s and 1s (a mask).
    min_x and min_y are the minimum number of 1s in each row and column, respectively.
    This function returns a new data array, where each row and column has at least min_x and min_y 1s, respectively, and there are as few 1s as possible.
    '''
    best_solution = data
    score = np.sum(best_solution)
    # format: {matrix.tobytes(): (best_matrix, score)}

    memo = {}

    if np.any(np.sum(data, axis=0) < min_y) or np.any(np.sum(data, axis=1) < min_x):
        return None

    def get_best(data, main=False) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, int]:
        '''Gets the matrix with the lowest score, given the constraints.
        Uses memoization.
        '''
        nonlocal memo
        if data.tobytes() in memo:
            return memo[data.tobytes()]
        
        # Find the rows with more than min_x 1s
        can_remove_rows = np.sum(data, axis=1) > min_x
        # Find the columns with more than min_y 1s
        can_remove_columns = np.sum(data, axis=0) > min_y

        if (not np.any(can_remove_rows)) or (not np.any(can_remove_columns)):
            # If there's no row or column where we can remove a 1, we're done
            ans = (data, np.sum(data))
            memo[data.tobytes()] = (data, np.sum(data))
            return ans
        
        # Try removing each combination of rows and columns where we can remove a 1
        best = data, np.sum(data)
        # print(np.nonzero(can_remove_rows))
        # print(np.nonzero(can_remove_columns))
        iterator = product(np.nonzero(can_remove_rows)[0], np.nonzero(can_remove_columns)[0])
        if main:
            iterator = tqdm(list(iterator))
        for row, col in iterator:
            # print(row, col)
            if data[row, col] == 0:
                continue
            
            # Remove the 1 at (row, col)
            new_data = data.copy()
            new_data[row, col] = 0

            # Check if the new matrix is valid
            if np.any(np.sum(new_data, axis=0) < min_y) or np.any(np.sum(new_data, axis=1) < min_x):
                continue

            # Recurse
            new_best = get_best(new_data)
            if new_best[1] < best[1]:
                best = new_best

        memo[data.tobytes()] = best
        return best

    get_best(data, main=True)
    best = memo[data.tobytes()][0]
    return best

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create a random 5x5 binary matrix
    data = np.random.randint(0, 2, (5, 5))
    print(data)
    print("computing")
    ans = min_dataset(data, 1, 1)
    print("Solution:")
    print(ans)
    print("Score (lower is better; None means no solution was found.):")
    print(np.sum(ans))
```

Sample output:

```
 [[0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 0 1 1]
 [0 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0 1]]
computing
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:02<00:00,  8.27it/s]
Solution:
[[0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0]]
Score (lower is better; None means no solution was found.):
5
```

However, as soon as I start using 10x10 matrices, the code runs very slowly, and I need to be able to run this for 20000x500 matrices.

How can I speed up my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very different approach.

This problem can be formulated as an easy to write, but very,very large MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) model:

```
 # data
 i = 1..20000
 j = 1..500  
 A[i,j] : boolean matrix with about 10% ones
 r[i]   : minimum row sums (about 0.5 of row sums in A)
 c[j]   : minimum column sums (about 0.5 of column sums in A)     

 # model
 minimize sum((i,j), A[i,j]*x[i,j])
 subject to
        sum(j, A[i,j]*x[i,j]) >= r[i]   ∀i
        sum(i, A[i,j]*x[i,j]) >= c[j]   ∀j
        x[i,j] ∈ {0,1}
```

This is a very large MIP with more than 20k constraints and 1 million binary variables. (Not counting x[i,j] for which A[i,j]=0. I skipped those.). We can solve this as an LP by relaxing the binary variables. The solution will be automatically integer-valued. That would bring the solution time down to just 14 seconds. If needed, this can also be formulated as a network optimization problem. This takes just a few seconds.

Statistics

Size

```
  ---   20,501 rows  999,470 columns  2,998,408 non-zeroes
  ---   999,469 discrete-columns
```

LP timings

```
Dual simplex solved model.
--- LP status (1): optimal.
--- Cplex Time: 14.11sec (det. 10018.76 ticks)
Optimal solution found
Objective:       504711.000000
```

Network solver

```
Network - Optimal:  Objective =    5.0471100000e+05
Network time = 3.22 sec. (1050.56 ticks)  Iterations = 1235117 (1235117)
--- LP status (1): optimal.
--- Cplex Time: 4.05sec (det. 1859.71 ticks)
Optimal solution found
Objective:       504711.000000
```

An example using a network algorithm directly can be found here: https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2023/05/solving-as-network-with-lowerbounds.html.

---

Added by poster

Using GPT-4 to turn this into working code, we end up with:

```
import random
from pulp import LpProblem, LpMinimize, LpVariable, lpSum, LpBinary, LpStatus # pip install pulp
import numpy as np # pip install numpy (not required - just used for printing at the end)

def create_data(n_rows, n_cols):
    A = [[random.choice([0, 1]) for _ in range(n_cols)] for _ in range(n_rows)]
    # in my case, this will be r = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2] and c = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3] or something similar
    r = [int(sum(row) * 0.5) for row in A]
    c = [int(sum(col) * 0.5) for col in zip(*A)]
    return A, r, c

def solve_mip(A, r, c):
    n_rows = len(A)
    n_cols = len(A[0])

    prob = LpProblem("MIP_Problem", LpMinimize)

    x = [[LpVariable(f"x_{i}_{j}", cat=LpBinary) for j in range(n_cols)] for i in range(n_rows)]

    prob += lpSum(A[i][j] * x[i][j] for i in range(n_rows) for j in range(n_cols))

    for i in range(n_rows):
        prob += lpSum(A[i][j] * x[i][j] for j in range(n_cols)) >= r[i]

    for j in range(n_cols):
        prob += lpSum(A[i][j] * x[i][j] for i in range(n_rows)) >= c[j]

    prob.solve()

    if LpStatus[prob.status] == "Optimal":
        return [[int(x[i][j].value()) if x[i][j].value() is not None else None for j in range(n_cols)] for i in range(n_rows)]
    else:
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n_rows = 5
    n_cols = 5
    A, r, c = create_data(n_rows, n_cols)
    print("A:", A)
    print("r:", r)
    print("c:", c)

    result = solve_mip(A, r, c)
    if result is not None:
        print("Result:", result)
    else:
        print("No solution found.")

    print(f"A: {np.array(A)}")
    print(f"r: {np.array(r).reshape(-1, 1)}")
    print(f"c: {np.array(c)}")
    # nan means that it didn't matter what the value was
    # these can be set to 0 to get the array we want
    print(f"Result:\n{np.array(result, dtype=np.float32)}")
```

Comment: Ah, I was debating doing something like this but was out of practice! Thank you for showing that it's possible!

Comment: what code / program did you use to solve the problem? My code is running for an extremely long time.

Comment: I used here GAMS+Cplex. I also checked with other solvers. Most of them solve this very quickly (it is an easy but large LP). As stated, this can also be solved as a network problem for even better performance. It should not take more than a couple of seconds.